# Cassandra Spark Connector version conflict with spark 2.2

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, spark-cassandra-connector

I am getting the below error while running the spark job. Please suggest the correct version for the spark and Cassandra connector.

Below is my build.sbt

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

 

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.2.0-cdh6.0.1" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.0-cdh6.0.1" % "provided", // excludeAll ExclusionRule(organization = "javax.servlet"),
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.0-cdh6.0.1" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "`enter code here`spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % "2.2.0-cdh6.0.1",
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-client" % "2.0.0-cdh6.0.1",
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-common" % "2.0.0-cdh6.0.1",
  "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "2.0.10",
  "net.liftweb" %% "lift-json" % "3.3.0",
  "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.2.1"
)
```

I am getting the below  ERROR once submit the job on a spark

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/configuration/ConfigurationException
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.streaming.DStreamFunctions.saveToCassandra$default$4(DStreamFunctions.scala:47)
    at com.StreamingPrerequisiteLoad$.main(StreamingPrerequisiteLoad.scala:72)
    at com.StreamingPrerequisiteLoad.main(StreamingPrerequisiteLoad.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
```

Answer (score 4):

I faced similar issue with spark-cassandra-connector , so how'd it worked have a look,
For spark version 2.2 and scala 11.8.0, spark-cassandra-connector 2.3.0 will work .Also 
add commons-configuration 1.9 version jar , as it will throw exception  NoClassDefFound:/org/apache/commons/configuration/ConfigurationException . 
Try with following dependencies :

```
    version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.0" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.2.0" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.0" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "net.liftweb" %% "lift-json" % "3.0.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % "2.0.0" //% "provided"
libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "2.3.0" //% "provided"
libraryDependencies += "commons-configuration" % "commons-configuration" % "1.9" //% "provided"

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("org", "apache", "spark", "unused", "UnusedStubClass.class") => MergeStrategy.first
  case x => (mergeStrategy in assembly).value(x)
}
```